# Edit xml property in node

Tags: c, libxml2

How do i edit an XML nodes property?

I have tried using xmlNewProp, however, that does not overwrite the property. It just adds a new one.

So I was wondering if there is a way to either remove that property, or edit the propery.

Edit:

I understand that some people did not quite get what I was trying to do. Well, the thing was that I needed a way in C using libxml2 to update a nodes properties. I tried using xmlNewProp, however that did not work.

Someone suggested xmlSetProp, and that worked fine. My problem were that the documentation for lxml were huge, and it was difficult to locate the needed functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on `libxml` documentation, you can use `xmlSetProp` to set an attribute from a node.

http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlSetProp

Comment: Thanks! I have been searching through that documentation for a while without finding that.